# Google Cloud Storage Client Library 400 error on devserver as of update 1.8.8

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, client-library

I haven't changed any code, but when I try to upload an image file using the GCS Client library on app engine's dev server, I am now getting this fatal error:

Expect status [201] from Google Storage. But got status 400.

This was working until I made the update from Google to 1.8.8 as of 11/19/13.

Anybody else seeing this? It doesn't give any other indications as to why the 400 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you updated gcs client to 1.8.8 version from the downloads list, or to SVN head? Thanks.

Comment: Is this something I should look to update for each new GAE release?